# how can open another activity by action buttons in the dialog box which is opened with a button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make an app where I open a dialog box with a button. Then the dialog box would have two action buttons which opens two different activities.

Comment: What's not working? Please post your code with stack traces, So that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.setTitle("Title")
.setMessage("Show Message here")
.setPositiveButton("Button A", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityA));  

    }
})

.setNegativeButton("Button B", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
     startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityB));

    }
})
.show();
```